# How to select other Welcome Email in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, list, email-studio

I created a new list for subscribers and want to set up a welcome email but when I try to choose emails, there is one basic test email appears. How can I select email which I created earlier from "Content"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Welcome Emails on lists are only able to use Classic Emails. The reason this is a major issue is that SFMC has sunset the classic content and Classic Emails to no longer be able to be used. This means that essentially this capability can no longer be used.

Your best bet is to complain to your Account Rep and see what they can do. Other then that, you will need to build your own process for welcome emails, which are not always that easy to do and likely will require you to use Data Extensions instead of lists.

Comment: Oh, it's a bad news, but thank you for answer.